# Error: 101 object not found for update

Tags: parse-platform

I've got the follwing parse.com cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Action", function (request) {

var BookStatus = Parse.Object.extend("BookStatus");
var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
var book = new Book();

var actionType = request.object.get("actionTypePointer").id;
var bookId = request.object.get("bookPointer").id;

var queryBook = new Parse.Query("Book");
var newBookStatus;

queryBook.get(bookId,{
    success: function (gottenBook) {

        newBookStatus = "idOfTheBookStatus"; 

        book.id = bookId;
        book.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));
        gottenBook.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));

        //OPTION 1
        gottenBook.save(null,{
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Bookstatus updated1");
            },
            error: function (data,error) {
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
        //OPTION 2
        book.save(null,{
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Bookstatus updated2");
            },
            error: function (data,error) {
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });

    },
    error: function (object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

});
```

OPTION1 
I try to save the queried book after setting the bookStatus to the returned book.

OPTION2
I try to save the new book object after setting the book.Id

```
        book.id = bookId;
        book.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));
```

However with any of the 2 options I end up getting in the parse.com logs:

Error: 101 object not found for update
 Error: 101 object not found for update

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT

New implementation with fetch:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Action", function (request) {

var BookStatus = Parse.Object.extend("BookStatus");
var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
var book = new Book();

var actionType = request.object.get("actionTypePointer").id;
var bookId = request.object.get("bookPointer").id;

book.id = bookId;
console.log("before fetch book.id" + book.id);
var newBookStatus;

book.fetch({
    success: function (book) {
        newBookStatus = "XMFkXS9NVv";            

        book.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));

        console.log("book" + book);
        console.log("book.id" + book.id);
        console.log("book.isValid()" + book.isValid());

        book.save(null,{
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Book Status updated to:" +newBookStatus);
            },
            error: function (data,error) {
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

});
```

});

With result:

```
  Input: {"place":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":41.354643806134625,"longitude":2.121594674804572},"bookLocationDescription":"sad","bookPointer":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Book","objectId":"kWcALge4az"},"actionTypePointer":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"ActionType","objectId":"kJC954w9iO"},"userPointer":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"6xpiAHX9Ju"},"createdAt":"2013-05-16T13:59:33.810Z","updatedAt":"2013-05-16T13:59:33.810Z","objectId":"PwlXhKL51l","ACL":{"6xpiAHX9Ju":{"read":true,"write":true},"*":{"read":true}}}
  Result: Success

I2013-05-15T20:52:19.170Z] before fetch book.idc1iKxw3NLD
I2013-05-15T20:52:19.273Z] book[object Object]
I2013-05-15T20:52:19.273Z] book.idc1iKxw3NLD
I2013-05-15T20:52:19.273Z] book.isValid()true
I2013-05-15T20:52:19.325Z] Error: 101 object not found for update
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your afterSave hook is overwriting the fetched Book's object id. Even if you're setting the same object id on it, the object now thinks it's dirty and it's no longer a valid reference.

Avoid this by using the book returned by `get()` and not updating it's id:

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Action", function (request) {

        var BookStatus = Parse.Object.extend("BookStatus");
        var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
        var book = new Book();

        var actionType = request.object.get("actionTypePointer").id;
        var bookId = request.object.get("bookPointer").id;

        var queryBook = new Parse.Query("Book");

        var newBookStatus;

        queryBook.get(bookId,{
            success: function (book) {
                newBookStatus = "idOfTheBookStatus"; 

                book.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));

                book.save(null,{
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Bookstatus updated1");
                    },
                    error: function (data,error) {
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (object, error) {
                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }

        });
    });
```

Since you already know the id for this book, instead of using a query, you can create a pointer and fetch it directly.

Final afterSave hook:

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Action", function (request) {

        var BookStatus = Parse.Object.extend("BookStatus");
        var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
        var book = new Book();

        var actionType = request.object.get("actionTypePointer").id;
        var bookId = request.object.get("bookPointer").id;

        book.id = bookId;

        var newBookStatus;

        book.fetch({
            success: function (book) {
                newBookStatus = "idOfTheBookStatus"; 

                book.set("bookStatus", new BookStatus({id: newBookStatus}));

                book.save(null,{
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Bookstatus updated1");
                    },
                    error: function (data,error) {
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (object, error) {
                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: The first after afterSave hook seems to me like my Option1 I used. The option 2 was being "dirtied" by me setting again the id I got this now! I updated the question with the code I got from your second answer. Thanks for your help @Hector Ramos

Comment: Does this book object have an ACL which does not grant you write access? The log statements seem to indicate that you don't have permission to save that object, only read it.

Comment: var newAcl = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current());
                newAcl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
                book.setACL(newAcl); witch ends up in the cloud code like: "ACL":{"6xpiAHX9Ju":{"read":true,"write":true},"*":{"read":true}}}

Comment: I tried also to not set the ACL but I had the same luck . . .

Comment: Are you logged in as the user with object id 6xpiAHX9Ju? That's the only user who is allowed to save the book object.

Comment: I had on localstorage a user that no longer existed! asecond error I had it was that in my cloud code I had 2 events hooked After save for Action and book - After save Action saved a book and after save book also saved an action, I got into some loop there however parse managed to not get so deep into it! Thanks @Hector Ramos

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it after some running around

```
ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, "*******", "******");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

// save the installation
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

More info on the issue in my blog post here:
http://aprogrammersday.blogspot.com/2015/02/fix-parse-101-error-object-not-found.html

Answer (score 0):

Whilst looking for this error I found this thread the most useful. I wanted to add that `object not found for get` can also essentially mean `foreign key reference not found`.

The `not found for get` error can be incredibly unhelpful; for me it wasn't even giving a line number where the error was occurring, the error message is very vague and I could not find reference to the phrase in any of the documentation.

If you are getting this error, you will find a lot of reference to permissions issues, but if you are already using the `master key` then you need to find the object that is being referenced by a foreign key on your selected object.